# Evaluation of EllipticK on the branch cut

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, complex

The complete elliptic integral of the first kind $K(x)$ has a branch cut on the real axis for $|x|>0$.

One has:
\begin{align}
&1.) \qquad \lim_{\eta \to 0^-}K(x+i\eta)=K(x) &\text{ with } x,\eta\in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } x>1 \\
&2.) \qquad \lim_{\eta \to 0^+}K(x+i\eta)=K(x)+2i K(1-x) &\text{ with } x,\eta\in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } x>1 
\end{align}

Therefore, for an evaluation on the branch cut, I have to chose an $i \eta$ prescription. My numerical tests suggest, that *Mathematica* has the default prescription $1.)$, but I want to be absolutely certain.

Can someone please point me to a page of *Mathematica* or something else, which confirms that *Mathematica* has a default prescription and that it is $1.)$.

On a side note:
I am aware of the fact, that I could use functional identities of $K$ to map the evaluation to arguments to $|x|<1$ where everything is nice and cosy, but I would rather avoid them for some specific reasons.

Comment: The [Wolfram Functions website](http://functions.wolfram.com/)
 describes [the branch cut of the complete elliptic integral](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticK/04/05/) as you do.  I have always *assumed* that the conventions are the same between the Wolfram Functions website and the Mathematica software, but I admittedly do not know for sure.

Comment: Also, a "brunch cut" (line below the equations) sounds pretty tasty.  :-)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thx!

Comment: @MichaelSeifert But how do I know, what value it gives me if I evaluate e.g. EllipticK[2]? Does it evaluate ``K[2]+2 I K[-1]" or "K[2]"?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I do understand now, what you meant and that you answered my question already... Sry, for me being so slow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the directional limits will reveal *Mathematica*'s conventions:

```
Assuming[x > 1, Limit[EllipticK[x + I ε], ε -> 0, Direction -> 1]]
```

> `EllipticK[x]`

```
Assuming[x > 1, Limit[EllipticK[x + I ε], ε -> 0, Direction -> -1]]
```

> `2 I EllipticK[1 - x] + EllipticK[x]`

Comment: many thanks. good idea!